# Can you implement Sharding in PoW?

Tags: proof-of-stake, proof-of-work, scalability, sharding

Can you implement Sharding in a Blockchain with Proof of Work? And in a Blockchain with Proof of Stake? Thank you for clarification.

Comment: Yes, sharding is planned to be implemented during PoW and transition to full PoS. For details, see: **[R&D](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/R&D)**

- [Sharding introduction and R&D Compendium](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Sharding-introduction-R&D-compendium)
- [Sharding FAQ](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Sharding-FAQ)
- [Proof of Stake FAQ](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Proof-of-Stake-FAQ)